# How to read last x hours of a log file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a log file called "batch.log" which if the 3rd column records a "F" status for failure it will gzip that file using the name from column 5. I'm trying to only pull the last 24 hours of the log file so i don't get duplicate backups

Example of log file:

```
2222  20170723060312  C  3434  /batchprocessing/abc.dat
3333  20170723210057  C  2222 /batchprocessing/mnop.dat
4444  20170724030057  F  2223 /batchprocessing/xyz.dat
```

Code:

```
today=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
while read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 ; do
    if [ "${f3}" = "F" ] ; then
        gzip -c "${f5}" > /backup/batch_backups/"$(basename "${f5}")"_$today.gz
    else
          echo "No Error!"
    fi
done < batch.log
```

Answer (score 1):

With some relatively minor changes, you can convert `today` into *seconds-since-epoch* by using the `%s` format specifier and then using the parameter expansion for string index convert your `f2` to a date in seconds since epoch. Then all that needs to be done is to compare that `today - logdate < 86400` seconds. You can use the numeric `((... < ...))` comparison or use the older `[ ... -lt ... ]` comparison, though using the `((...))` format for numeric comparisons is suggested.

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
today=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
todaysecs=$(date "+%s")             ## get today in seconds since epoch
while read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 ; do
    f2date="${f2:0:4}-${f2:4:2}-${f2:6:2}"      ## get date part of f2
    f2time="${f2:8:2}:${f2:10:2}:${f2:12:2}"    ## get time part of f2
    logsecs=$(date -d "$f2date $f2time" +%s)    ## get f2 seconds since epoch
    ## require both $f3 = "f" and todaysecs - logsecs) < 86400
    if [ "${f3}" = "F" ] && (((todaysecs - logsecs) < 86400)); then
        gzip -c "${f5}" > /backup/batch_backups/"$(basename "${f5}")"_$today.gz
    else
        echo "No Error!"
    fi
done < batch.log
```

(avoid using backticks for *command substitution* instead use `$(cmd)`)

**note:** `logsecs` can be computed in a single command, e.g.

```
logsecs=$(date -d "${f2:0:4}-${f2:4:2}-${f2:6:2} ${f2:8:2}:${f2:10:2}:${f2:12:2}" +%s)
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: @David-C-Rankin Thank your for your detailed suggestion! Do you have a similar example of doing this in Solaris? My version doesn't have the `date -d` option so I get this error `date: illegal option -- d
usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff` It looks like my only options for `date` is either `u or a` Thanks again for your suggestion!!!

Comment: OOOOh... Let me dig into what Solaris has. Since seconds since epoch is the basis for timekeeping on Nix'es, there is no doubt a way, but being a Solaris noob, I'll have to do a bit of poking around.

Comment: @FrankRobertson - looks like Solaris and SunOS have only `-a` and `-u` options. That leaves you needing to compute the number of seconds for each log entry manually. That isn't too bad, just an accounting problem of summing the seconds in the separated years, months, days and time since Jan. 1. 1970. (which will be like `$(((${f2:0:4} - 1970) * 86400 * 365))` to get the seconds for the year difference -- and on down the line. Summing all the parts will give you the total seconds. (of course `date -d` is a hell of a lot easier `:)`